# Returning bool value with LINQ foreach

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking for a way to exchange the normal foreach loop for class' properties with LINQ, but LINQ foreach returns void. Here is the code(not working in current state):

```cs
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == this)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
        return false;
    //foreach (var e in properties)
    //{
    //    if (Equals(e.GetValue(obj), e.GetValue(this)))
    //        continue;
    //    else return false;
    //}
    return properties.ToList().ForEach((e => Equals(e.GetValue(obj), e.GetValue(this)));
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `List<T>.ForEach` isn't LINQ. It's a method of `List<T>`. Someone corrected me on that a few weeks ago and I'm just paying it forward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't specified, but I'm guessing you want the results to be `AND`ed - that is, return false if any property equality return false, and true if and only if all property equalities return true.

```
return properties.All(e => e.Equals(e.GetValue(obj), e.GetValue(this));
```

A foreach solution, just for reference, is to simply return false on the first false value found, and return true outside the loop:

```
foreach (var e in properties)
{
    if (!Equals(e.GetValue(obj), e.GetValue(this)))
        return false;
}
return true; // all passed
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing an aggregation of the results in the way you like:

```cs
 public override bool Equals(object obj)
 {
   if (obj == this)
     return true;
   if (obj == null)
     return false;
   if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
     return false;
   return properties.Aggregate(true, (acc, e) => acc && Equals(e.GetValue(obj), e.GetValue(this)));
}
```